# Localhost upload Wordpress Database

Tags: database, wordpress

I uploaded my portfolio.local to my server online. I exported the database and imported it on the server, the problem I have is that all links still point to portfolio.local and if I enter to login online, after I login the admin get's me to portfolio.local instead of the wp-admin on the server. I have already modified the wp-config.php file on the server...

What is the problem?

Comment: My answer in this thread will help you Diego: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069548/how-to-push-wordpress-from-mamp-into-hostgator/12070827#12070827

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to update the link structure in your database....
you need to edit the one you exported, delete the current one and then import the edited one.

**Example (some address in your database):**

```
http://localhost/mysite/?p=1
```

.
**Should Be:**

```
http://www.your-new-site.com/?p=1
```

.
**if you are using permalinks:**
i would delete the .htaccess file and recreate a new
on using your new website admin panel.

.
Hope this helps.
Awaiting your replay
Sagive.