# Moving 3 year old Wordpress site to new server

Tags: wordpress

I have been put to task to move a Wordpress site made in 2010 to a new server. I dont have access to the old websites admin panel, but have been given the source files and exported version of the database. The website has a number of plugins installed and I think it will more difficult to transfer over all the old files etc over a fresh install hence I want to make the old site to work.

I have copied over all of the files into my testing server, and made changes to the wp_config.php file to find the new database location. The issue is that all of the links appear to be from the old website. Logically I assume I need to change both the absolute path and then the links to the individual posts.

Where do I change these values and are there any other files/values I need to change to ensure the website works perfectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll see lots of different approaches to this (migration scripts/plugins, exporting/importing etc).  I'm assuming here that your problem stems from changing the domain the site is running on, which is different from changing the server?.

For me the best way by miles to transfer a Wordpress site is using the following answer I gave here - the Interconnectit script is a major time and hassle saver.

[How to push wordpress from mamp into hostgator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069548/how-to-push-wordpress-from-mamp-into-hostgator/12070827#12070827)

Answer (score 0):

Usually this will do, in your wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://new-path.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://new-path.com');
```

If thats not enough add a plugin called "Search and Replace", and search for the old URL, and replace with your new one.

Comment: Hey ninja, these defines are not located in this wp_config, might be a very old wordpress version (Version 3.1.4)

Comment: You can just add them yourself, it should be supported granted your not using WP 2.0 or below.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach worked for me. The Themes also migrated properly.

How to move Wordpress Setup from one server to another server (With different domain names)

```
1.Export Files & DB from the source server.
2.Import Files & DB into the target server (As it is)
3.Delete *_options table from the target server DB.
4.Export only the *_options table from the source server DB.
5.Find & Replace the old domain name with the new domain name in the above .sql file
6.Import the above modified *_options table into target server DB.
7.Open wp-config.php file in target server and update the new DB connection info.
8.Open .htaccess file in target server and put the default entry for WordPress.
9.Login into the target server WP Admin Panel
10.Install and activate a plugin called “Velvet Blues Update URLs”.
11.Go to Tools -> Update URLs
12.Replace all the following possible URLs with the new domain name

http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
http://example.com
https://example.com

13.Test the target server site
```